# R - Add a new ID for each data frame within a list (using apply or dplyr)

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, apply

For each data frame, I want a unique identifier. I already can do this using a for loop, but I'm trying to make my code more R-like, and I feel like this could be done with an `apply` function or `dplyr`. My current code example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x="ayyy", y=rnorm(5))
df2 <- data.frame(x="lmao", y=rnorm(6))
l1 <- list(df1,df2)

for (i in seq_along(l1)){
  l1[[i]] <- cbind(l1[[i]],i)
}


l1
```

I would also appreciate other methods of achieving this end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `mapply`:

`mapply(cbind, l1, "i" = seq_along(l1), SIMPLIFY = F)`

Output:

```
[[1]]
     x           y i
1 ayyy  1.52049119 1
2 ayyy  0.79595595 1
3 ayyy -1.45352957 1
4 ayyy  0.09839542 1
5 ayyy -0.59377098 1

[[2]]
     x           y i
1 lmao  0.88828117 2
2 lmao  0.05307042 2
3 lmao -0.55702363 2
4 lmao  0.43839704 2
5 lmao  0.15260816 2
6 lmao -0.16461758 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `purrr::imap` for this, which passes the index of each element in the list as a second argument `.y` to the function:

```
library(purrr); library(dplyr)

imap(l1, ~ mutate(.x, i = .y))

#[[1]]
#     x         y i
#1 ayyy -1.761054 1
#2 ayyy -2.123735 1
#3 ayyy -1.525554 1
#4 ayyy -1.756684 1
#5 ayyy -1.686749 1

#[[2]]
#     x           y i
#1 lmao  0.05505287 2
#2 lmao -0.33393283 2
#3 lmao -1.91543274 2
#4 lmao -1.03591717 2
#5 lmao  0.67857511 2
#6 lmao  0.61049477 2
```

Which is equivalent to a base R solution using `Map`:

```
Map(function(.x, .y) mutate(.x, i = .y), l1, seq_along(l1))
```

Notice with `lapply` or `apply` you don't have the ability to track the index of each element while looping through them.